# How can I show that a Lyapunov operator is monotone?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is stable (i.e. all of its eigenvalues have negative real parts), and $X$ satisfies the Lyapunov equation $A^\star X + XA = -Q$, where $A^\star$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$ and $Q$ is a symmetric matrix. If $Y$ satisfies $A^\star Y + YA \leq -Q$, how can I show that $Y \geq X$? Here is what I've tried:

In the case that $Y$ satisfies $A^\star Y + YA = -Q$, then $Y = X$ because $X$ is the unique solution to $A^\star X + XA = -Q$ (since $A$ is stable). Therefore, we need to show that if $Y$ satisfies $A^\star Y + YA < -Q$, then $Y > X$. Because $A^\star X + XA = -Q$, then $Y$ satisfies
\begin{align}
A^\star Y + YA &< A^\star X + XA \\
A^\star (Y - X) + (Y - X)A &< 0
\end{align}
I'm not sure how to proceed from here. My first thought is that because all the eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real parts, then $A$ must be negative-definite. Therefore, $Y-X$ must be positive definite for the inequality above to be true, which completes the proof. However, I'm not sure about this logic.

Comment: $A^\ast Z+ZA=-H$ is uniquely solved by $Z=\int_0^\infty e^{tA^\ast}He^{tA}dt$.

Comment: @user1551 I've tried this: $$\begin{align}X &= \int_0^\infty e^{tA^*} Q e^{tA} dt \\ &\leq \int_0^\infty e^{tA^*} (-A^* Y - YA) e^{tA} dt \end{align}$$ but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Yes, and the last line is equal to $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @user1551's hints,
\begin{align}
X &= \int_0^\infty e^{tA^*} Q e^{tA} \, dt \\
&\leq \int_0^\infty e^{tA^*} (-A^* Y - YA) e^{tA} \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty -e^{tA^*} A^* Y e^{tA} - e^{tA^*} YAe^{tA} \, dt
\end{align}
Now let
\begin{align}
u(t) &= -e^{tA^*} \\
v(t) &= Ye^{tA}
\end{align}
Such that
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dt}(t) &= -e^{tA^*} A^* \\
\frac{dv}{dt}(t) &= YAe^{tA}
\end{align}
Then, using the product rule of differentiation,
\begin{align}
X &\leq \int_0^\infty -e^{tA^*} A^* Y e^{tA} - e^{tA^*} YAe^{tA} \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{du}{dt}(t) v(t) + u(t) \frac{dv}{dt}(t) \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dt}(u(t)v(t)) \, dt \\
&= [u(t)v(t)]_0^\infty \\
&= \left[-e^{tA^*}Ye^{tA}\right]_0^\infty
\end{align}
Because $A$ is stable, then $\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{tA} = 0$, and so
\begin{align}
X &\leq \left[-e^{tA^*}Ye^{tA}\right]_0^\infty \\
&= \lim_{t \to \infty} \left[-e^{tA^*}Ye^{tA}\right] - \left[-e^{0A^*}Ye^{0A}\right] \\
&= Y
\end{align}
and so $$Y \geq X$$